# Why is there a huge gap on top of my TOC?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, vertical-alignment

[image]

I tried to delete all the geometry and delete the usepackage{geometry} and all the margins and everything but end up the TOC is still away from my top a lot. I want it to have 50mm away from the top. i've printed it out and measured it. It's 85mm..

Even my list of figures, tables, listings are all 85mm...

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %times font
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %roman & arabic label page
\usepackage[top=50mm, bottom=50mm, left=45mm, right=45mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{tocbibind} %for hyperref
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{apacite} %cite apa
\usepackage{array} %for table width
\usepackage{listings} %codes
\usepackage{caption} % code caption
\usepackage{color} % code caption
\usepackage{xcolor} %code caption
\usepackage{titlesec} % set section/subsection fontstyle & fontsize

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{14}\bfseries\itshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries\itshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}


\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections     linked
linkcolor = black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
urlcolor=blue, % for \url
citecolor=black, 
}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{document}
\input{CoverPage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\input{TitlePage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage


\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Copyright}
\input{CopyrightPage}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\cleardoublepage


\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\input{DeclarationPage}
\cleardoublepage


\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgement}
\input{AcknowledgementPage}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Management Summary}
\input{ManagementSummaryPage}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Algorithms}
\lstlistoflistings
\cleardoublepage

% % (1) =========================================

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1 : Introduction}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\input{Chapter1}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2 : Background Study }
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\input{Chapter2}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 3 : Requirements \& Design}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\input{Chapter3}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 4 : Implementation Plan}
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\input{Chapter4}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 5 : Conclusion}
\setcounter{chapter}{5}
\input{Chapter5}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Reference}
\setcounter{chapter}{6}
\input{References}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\input{Appendix}
\cleardoublepage


\end{document}
```

Comment: Presumably that is the design for chapter headings in your class. since you have given no indication of the input, impossible to say anything.

Comment: As always, please post a MWE showing this problem. This is just the design of either `\chapter*` or `\section*` of your document

Comment: No [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), no answer.

Comment: Well, your edit is nice, but this is not a full example, starting at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`. Please, try to help us help you. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you try with `\chapter*{Introduction}` the result will be the same. If the question is “how to push the title of an unnumbered chapter up to the text block border?” then it may receive an answer, provided you tell what document class you're using.

Comment: @yo' isit okay now? o.o

Comment: @egreg actually i dont quite understand you.. @@

Comment: @Michimcchicken Well, you use `\input` many times on files we don't have, making the example far from minimal. It's better though because now we at least know what exactly are you doing. I'm working on an answer.

Comment: @yo' sorry.. @@ and thanks.. hope to hear from you soon T_T

Comment: @Michimcchicken The code I show in the answer would have been a good minimal example: Showing all the packages you load, but not too long (two chapters is fine to show all needed), and not dependent on other files (I use `blindtext` to provide some dummy text, but whatever dummy text you get is good; here it's necessary to make the text long enough so that it gets to the next page and shows the page margins). I'm sure you'll make a good MWE next time you ask a question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is: to modify the spacing around chapter titles. This is done for instance by using the package `titlesec`:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}%
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*\chapter{0pt}{10pt}{40pt}
```

You can fiddle with the values `10pt` and `40pt` to fine-tune the spacing to your liking.

---

Needed to say, there is more comments I have on your code:

- I don't understand **why you set the `chapter` counter each time, and why you use `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline` manually. That seems to be a big abuse of the system, things should be surely done another way.
- Note that if you want chapters to start on odd page, you can't use `[oneside]` and you have to add `[openright]` in the `report` class. The `book` class set `[twoside,openright]` as default.
- Instead of manually adding ToC, LoT etc. in the table of contents, you better use the package `{tocbibind}`.
- `hyperref` should be loaded after most other packages. `color` is not needed if you load `xcolor`.
- It's better not to use explicit `\fontsize{}{}` command but rely on the standard commands; `12pt` is `\normalsize` for your setup, and `14pt` is `\large`. If you decide to use `\fontsize`, the 2nd number should be larger by ~20%, so `\fontsize{12}{14}` and `\fontsize{14.4}{17}` would have been better, for instance.

In the end, your code could look like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %times font
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %roman & arabic label page
\usepackage[top=50mm, bottom=50mm, left=45mm, right=45mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbibind} %for hyperref
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{apacite} %cite apa
\usepackage{array} %for table width
\usepackage{listings} %codes
\usepackage{caption} % code caption
\usepackage{xcolor} % code caption

\usepackage{blindtext} % to provide some dummy text

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}%
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*\chapter{0pt}{10pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries\itshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections     linked
linkcolor = black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
urlcolor=blue, % for \url
citecolor=black, 
}

\begin{document}

% FRONTMATTER

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Algorithms}
\lstlistoflistings

% MAINMATTER

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\Blindtext


\chapter{Second Chapter}
\Blindtext


\end{document}
```

Comment: the 0pt 10pt and 40pt is what ah? as in 0pt is the beginning isit? 10 and 40 is?? o.o

Comment: and the {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge} can i use default and delete this line? o.o

Comment: @Michimcchicken This should make the default. If you don't use `\titleformat{\chapter}` at all, then `\titlespacing*{\chapter}` cannot do anything.

Comment: okayokay.. thank you so much.. i shall print and see.. thankssss <3

Comment: For the meaning of the dimensions in `\titlespacing`, read the [`titlesec` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec)

Comment: thanks for the other feedbacks... i've read all.. the phantom section i posted somequestion and someone helped me with it and asked me to add the phantom section because of the style that i kept \input \input... so the helper asked me to do so... as for the rest i'll try to fix.. thank you so much...

Comment: @Michimcchicken You're welcome :)

Comment: it is still lower than i expected.. i put \titlespacing*\chapter{0pt}{0pt}{20pt} but that's okay at least it went up for now..